# Maximum Nesting of levels in SQL Server after trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I created a new trigger that would let me create a log after updating, however even though i think it should work i get the following error:

> The maximum nesting level of views, stored procedures, functions or triggers was exceeded (limit: 32).

Is it possible that it has something to do with how the trigger is written?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [TR_Log_Notes]
ON ALUMNS
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Note_Text VARCHAR (30)
    SET @Note_Text = 'Fields were updated'

    INSERT INTO Log_Notes(Alumn_ID, Note_Text)
        SELECT i.Alumn_ID, @NoteText 
        FROM INSERTED i
END
```

Comment: Is there another trigger on the table Log_Notes?

Comment: yes there are 3 currently

Comment: Probably one of those triggers is causing the error.   You would need to post the code for them for us to help find it.  The trigger on ALUMNS as you have posted above is fine.

Comment: Something is a bit off here. You can't have a trigger that has the same name as a table in the same schema. Obviously you have changed something around because this would not work as posted. You would get a duplicate object name error. There is already an object named 'Log_Notes' in the database.

Comment: You are right, i am sorry, the name is TR_Log_Notes


Thanks

Comment: Is the trigger name the ONLY difference or is there some other code that didn't make it also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting into `log_notes` *after* updating a row in the same table.  Is that really what you intend?

If you do intend the same table, then you should use a `for` trigger, and update each row before it goes into the table.  However, I suspect that you want to create the trigger on a different table.

Comment: Hello

Yes, i created the Trigger on the table ALUMNS, and my intention is to insert the data into LOG_NOTES after ALUMNS is updated

Thanks